# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS without a web server

Tags: web-server, http, redirect, openvpn, https

I'm running an OpenVPN AS server on a VPS and the server itself has a web interface accessible through HTTPS. I'd like to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS without having to install a web server for just that purpose.

Is there any simple way to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS?

Comment: You need something to tell the web browser to redirect to the HTTPS address, otherwise you'll end up with non-encrypted traffic on a port that expects encrypted traffic. Basically, you can do it, but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to listen on the TCP/80 port and to respond with an HTTP header containing "Location:". That's the only way a web browser will understand, and do what you want. That is, by definition, a web server. Granted, you need this web server to do very very little.

I would look at [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net).

You could write a dead simple shell script, (or lang of your choosing,) which simply printed the Location: HTTP header, (and whatever other headers are needed,) regardless of whatever it receives as a request. Then Netcat can be used to make a TCP/80 listener wrapped around your shell script.

Comment: Great answer. I ended up just installing nginx, but this would be something I can look into in the future. Thanks :).